# How to set values of simple_form input and assign true false values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Firstly im new to Ruby and this could possibly be the wrong approach, however...

I'm trying to set two values in my select, using simple form. So far i have:

```
<%= f.input :rsvp, :collection => [:attending, :not_attending], :prompt => 'Choose one...' %>
```

This works fine, i can load the page, choose a selection. Now RSVP is a field in my db:

**reply DB**

```
class CreateReplies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :replies do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :menu
      t.integer :rsvp

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**reply.rb**

```
class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :menu, :name, :rsvp, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
end
```

My thinking was changing rsvp from :string where i have to type attending / not attending to an :integer so that i could yes likea true / false value on the two choices. Now like i said i'm very new to this, but in my head, this might be how to go about such a thing.

Because im going to try and get a count of how many are attending / not attending and display on the index. Sorry if anything is missing, let me know and ill update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you went on the right way. You can make a group radio button for user select, try:

```
<%= f.input :rsvp, :collection => [['Attending',1], ['Not Attending',0]], as: :radio_buttons, label_method: first, value_method: last, :prompt => 'Choose one...' %>
```

Or this way:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :rsvp, [[true, 'Attending'] ,[false, 'Not Attending']], :first, :last %>
```

Comment: what form you get error? `f.input` or `f.collection_radio_buttons`?

Comment: Actually the first one gives me an error, but the second one works - So now i get a true / false appear on my replies page. Can i then just run a count on this?

Comment: ahh, I see, sorry, I missed a commas :D Updated it. Please mark accept my answer if it solve your problem. Sure, you can use `Reply.count(rsvp: true)` Try it ;)

Comment: Accept, works really well. The only thing i need to work out is at the moment my index is showing true instead of attending a the value. I'm guessing due to the way im calling the reply.rsvp

Comment: I think you want show 'Attending', 'Not Attending' in your index?

Comment: Ahh unknown key for count, let me read up the api, so i can see where im going wrong :P

Comment: Ill try this tonight and let you know :)

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: true: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "replies"  WHERE (rsvp = true)

Comment: I think this because your `rsvp` in your table is `integer`, not boolean. Check your rsvp have what values and set for approriate.

Comment: t.boolean :rsvp, :default => false :(

Comment: oh, I see in your question it's integer type, so try change `true` to `false` to test if it works?

Comment: Still not working, could it be a problem with the checkboxes im using to set? its almost like its the actual settings of the values thats the problem. I'll try research the way im writing it out. Sorry to be a pain!